# Running ROS with DMA

Tags: arduino, serial, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an Arduino Due configured to use DMA with the following library: https://github.com/rblilja/DmaSerial. However, when I try to run the code in my sketch I get the following error
/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h:72:19: error: 'Serial' was not declared in this scope
iostream = &Serial;
I changed the extern reference to the Serial variable in the variant.h file from a UARTClass object to a DmaSerial object, called dmaSerial, which fixed the error above, but I still run into errors, and I am unsure exactly what to change in ROS to allow ROS to be configured with the arduino DMA. I currently get the following error,

undefined reference to `dmaSerial'

but it's on a line where there isn't even any code in my sketch, which is peculiar. If anyone has done this before or understands ROS well enough to tackle this issue that would be of great help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268870/running-ros-with-dma/) by [j3ven7](https://answers.ros.org/users/31355/j3ven7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-15**:
Can you post your terminal output (full error) and source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to add a case to use the object `dmaSerial` in the [ArduinoHardware.h](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/jade-devel/rosserial_arduino/src/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h#L78) file that you will found in the **ros_lib** folder.

---

Originally posted by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) with karma: 544 on 2017-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0